# Xamarin's Forms Chip Error on launch of app

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting the following error in Xamrain forms and their is no more detail I can give until you ask me as unfamiliar with the error never had it before.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     error: CGViewProvider_1 is not abstract and does not override
> abstract method checkView(View,int) in ChipItemViewProvider public
> class
> CGViewProvider_1  THEHOCKEYLAB.Android    D:\GitMaster\thehockeylabl.mobile\THEHOCKEYLAB\THEHOCKEYLAB.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\src\crc640a67887a4134e062\CGViewProvider_1.java   4

It seems to be something to do with their conversation code that converts the code into real time java, I see no obv way of getting to what the error is from here it happens on launch and cancels the build..

Its making a referring to ChipItemViewProdiver I have not changed processers or any part of my pc this application works.

If you let me no how to get extra debug info to diagnose this I would be greatfull

**Edit 2**

It would be appear to do with having fast debug on and the linker at the same time I am trailing it here and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by having the linker and fast debug switched on your settings for Android should be like this. To avoid the error.

[image]

BTW I didnt change this manually folks this was after VS Update